# File opening animation like in iBooks and Photos.app on iPad

Tags: iphone, file, animation, ibooks

When you open a PDF file in iBooks.app, its thumbnail expands to entire screen, then it shows a PDF page.
And when you open a photo in Photos.app on iPad, its thumbnail expands to entire screen too. Then you can swipe between pages, zoom it and so on. So, I would like to implement this animation in my application, but I have no idea how to do it.

Can you help me? Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple animation:

```
  // Begin animation
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

  // Maximize image size
  MyImage.frame = self.view.frame;

  // Commit animation
  [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I suggest looking into CAKeyframeAnimation if you want a more sophisticated animation. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAKeyframeAnimation